# Hide rows and columns on multiple sheets using a letter ("H") to hide and an integer ("0") to show

Tags: excel, vba

So far I have written below, but this debug window pops up on *# **While .Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""***

I bolded the issue down below. I have a workbook with "H" and "0"  in 1,A to specify which worksheet to show. If the worksheet is shown, additional "H" and "0" are running along Column A and Row 1. to hide specific columns and rows.

If anyone can find the issues below or write a better script, any help would be appreciated!

```
 Sub Format()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        Set startsheet = ActiveSheet
        Set StartCell = ActiveCell
        
        j = 0
        For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If Sheet.Visible = True Then j = j + 1
        Next
    
        
        For i = 1 To j
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Activate
            HideRows
            HideColumns
        Next
  
        startsheet.Activate
        StartCell.Activate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



Sub HideRows()
    Dim r As Long
        r = 1
        With ActiveSheet
            **While .Cells(r, 1).Value <> ""**
                If .Cells(r, 1).Value = "H" And Not .Rows(r).Hidden Then
                    .Rows(r).Hidden = True
                ElseIf .Cells(r, 1).Value <> "H" And .Rows(r).Hidden Then
                    .Rows(r).Hidden = False
                End If
                r = r + 1
            Wend
        End With
End Sub

Sub HideColumns()
    Dim c As Long
        c = 1
        With ActiveSheet
            While .Cells(1, c).Value <> ""
                If .Cells(1, c).Value = "H" And Not .Columns(c).Hidden Then
                    .Columns(c).Hidden = True
                ElseIf .Cells(1, c).Value <> "H" And .Columns(c).Hidden Then
                    .Columns(c).Hidden = False
                End If
                c = c + 1
            Wend
        End With
End Sub
```

I've tried using the macro recorder, but my worksheet is too massive and would cause the file to be too large to share over S Drive.

Comment: What does the error pop up says?

Comment: One possible error I see is that you only seem to want to loop through visible sheets which you attempt to gather by that first for each loop but what you're actually doing is just counting visible sheets, not gathering their indexes. The index of a worksheet is independent of the visibility of the sheet so I think your logic might be faulty and you need a different way to gather visible sheets. Either a collection of indexes or you can just loop through all sheets and call your functions on those that are visible.

Comment: I see in your code that you check a cell value against "H".... but I don't see you check against "0" ?? And "0" ---> is it zero ? or letter o ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: @FaridIbrahim The error reads: "Run time error 13 type mismatch"

Comment: @andrewb Thanks Andrew for the catch!

Comment: @karma It's zero. I used one Letter and one Number. I'll add the check against 0, thank you!